# Bash string concatenation producing weird results

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, string-concatenation

My bash code `file.sh` :

```
username=$1
pkgpath="/home/${username}_tmp.txt"
echo $username
echo $pkgpath
```

Now running the script with the command `bash file.sh abc` should produce the result :

```
abc
/home/abc_tmp.txt
```

But the output I'm getting is :

```
abc
_tmp.txtc
```

Can someone explain why is this behavior occurring and how to obtain the desired result ? 
**EDIT**
I'd like to mention that using `pkgpath="/home/${username}"` gives me `/home/abc` (desired) but running `pkgpath="${username}_tmp.txt"`gives me `_tmp.txt`(weird).

Comment: Are you saying you get an extra character `c` appended at the end when it is not likely to have? (apart from the variable value not expanded). Are you running this script on the command-line? Did you by chance edit the script in a Windows editor (Notepad++) may be?

Comment: I just copied/pasted it on my machine and it worked fine

Comment: Actually I was running through remotely logging into my RHEL5 desktop but it doesn't matter as I tried running directly on the desktop and same results

Comment: I edited on Sublime Text 3 and yes the output is exactly as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If the file has come from Windows then the line endings with their `\r` can cause these kinds of issues, particularly when you are editing on different platforms.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. The *first* thing it asks you to check before posting is if your script uses DOS line endings.

Comment: @iammrmehul, it's not necessarily this script that's buggy -- it could be whatever's calling it (and is thus providing the `$1`). But *something* is passing in DOS newlines. If you have a new enough (4.x) version of bash, `bash -x yourscript` will log execution with those escaped to be visible.

Comment: Running the command reveals `\r` after every line. How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are somehow inserting a carriage return character after `abc` when you run the command `bash file abc`. The culprit is probably either your terminal, or you are copy pasting the command and are including `^M` without realizing.

So what bash is outputting on the second line is really `/home/abc^M_tmp.txt`, which gets rendered as `_tmp.txtc`. You can easily verify this by piping the output of your command to `less -R`.

Comment: Yes there a ^M indeed. Please, how can I fix that

Comment: After referring to This Answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found
I just implemented Unix line ending from Windows line ending in sublime text and issue was resolved !